# can not delete cookie, it still show up call it in other file

Tags: php, cookies

create cookie

```
$cookie_name = "userw";
$cookie_value = "John due";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day

if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
```

delete cookie

```
// set the expiration date to one hour ago
$cookie_name = "userw";

setcookie("$cookie_name", "", time() - 3600);
unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);


$cookie_name = "userw";
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
```

read cookie after deleted

```
$cookie_name = "userw";
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
```

If I read the cookie in the file while with unset, the cookie does not appear. but when I read the cookie again it shows up. I test it in xampp.
Does anyone have any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

When removing the cookie, you need to specifiy the same path that you specified when creating it (unless you want to do very specific things):

Try this:

```
setcookie($cookie_name, '', time() - 3600, '/');   // note the 4th param, '/'
```

Comment: yes, those are in the same part. event if in one file, when I modify it to read the cookie only, it still shows up the cookie that I tried to delete it.

Comment: also check setcookie($cookie_name, '', time() - 3600, '/'); and it doesn't work for me

Comment: @VõMinh That's very surprising. You replaced `setcookie("$cookie_name", "", time() - 3600);` with `setcookie($cookie_name, '', time() - 3600, '/');` and it still doesn't work? There is no reason it shouldn't.

Comment: maybe I have mistake somewhere. let me check it back.

Comment: it is sad that I searched and try the same thing before but it not work. and after you comment it work..

Comment: @VõMinh Nice! Weird that it didn't work before indeed... (You can also mark the answer as accepted if you'd like)